# How to change the controller and the template dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

I have a page like below, and want to change the controller and the template of "cms-content" acording to the item clicked in "cms-header" dynamically.

Is there a good way to do this? I don't like to use $routeProvider.

```
<div id="cms-header"  ng-controller="CmsMenuCtrl">

</div>
<div id="cms-content">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use `ng-include` with separate controllers for each child template.

So, it would look something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="CmsMenuCtrl">
    <div id="cms-header">
        <button ng-click="select(0)">Product Details</button>
    </div>
    <div id="cms-content" ng-include="content"></div>
</div>
```

And the `CmsMenuCtrl`:

```
myApp.controller('CmsMenuCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.content = null;

    $scope.pages = ['productDetails.html', 'categories.html', 'checkout.html'];

    $scope.select = function(idx) {

        $scope.content = $scope.pages[idx]; // obviously index isn't the best way :)
    }
});
```

Then in the `productDetails.html` template something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="productDetailsCtrl">

  <!-- All the information on the scope of productDetailsCtrl -->
</div>
```

Comment: `content` will not be available outside the scope of the `CmdMenuCtrl`, though.

Comment: it doesn't need to be because it only holds the url to the template.

Comment: Isn't the `ng-include` outside the scope of the Controller and, hence, will be unable to get to the url of the template?

Comment: Now the `CmsMenuController` isn't only a _Menu controller_ and there are restrictions in place on the DOM hierarchy (`content` and `menu` in the same DOM). :-) (* nitpicking *) Wouldn't you say that a solution using a `navigation service` is slightly better?

Comment: Since it does not has a fixed number of choices, so will choose the 2nd one. musically_ut and DavinTryon, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of choices, then you can use `ng-switch` to do it. The nice thing about it is that you'll have all the template related information in the templates itself.

**Template**

```html
<div id="cms-header" ng-controller="CmsMenuCtrl">
    <nav>
        <button ng-click="selectItem('about')">About</button>
        <button ng-click="selectItem('home')">Home</button>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="cms-content" ng-controller="CmsContentCtrl">

    <div ng-switch="selectedItem()">
        <div ng-switch-when="about">
            <div ng-include="'about.html'" 
                 ng-controller="CmsAboutCtrl">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="home">
            <div ng-include="'home.html'" 
                 ng-controller="CmsHomeCtrl">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Other pages -->

    </div>
</div>
```

**Service to share navigation information**

This is your replacement for `$routeParameters`

```js
// navigationService to share information across controllers
myApp.service('navigationService', function () {
    var currentItem;

    this.selectItem(item) = function (item) {
        currentItem = item;
    };

    this.selectedItem() = function () {
        return item;
    };
});
```

**Controllers**

```
myApp.controller('CmsMenuCtrl', function ($scope, navigationService) {

    // ...

    $scope.selectItem = function (item) {
        navigationService.selectItem(item);
    };
});

myApp.controlelr('CmsContentCtrl', function ($scope, navigationService) {
    $scope.selectedItem = function () {
        return navigationService.selectedItem();
    }
});
```

---

Note that if you can define a controller which encompasses both components and then obviate the *service*. However, using a `naviagtionService` would be the preferred way.